# Angular pages loaded Multiple times when loading it with different param values

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I do not know if this is a bug or a feature or a mistake on my side, but what I am trying to do is having a page for contracts and a page for chats (which has one chat per corresponding contract).

Now depending one which chat or which contract is opened my url changes:

`david/contracts` -> `david/contracts/12`

`david/chats` -> `david/chats/12`

with the contract id at the end as param.

My routing module looks like this:

```js
{
  canActivate: [GlobalsProviderInit, SessionDataLoadedGuard, AuthGuard],
    path: ':username/chat',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: () => import('./pages/chat/chat.module').then(m => m.ChatPageModule)
        },
        {
          path: ':id',
          loadChildren: () => import('./pages/chat/chat.module').then(m => m.ChatPageModule)
        }
      ]
},
{
  path: ':username/contracts',
    canActivate: [GlobalsProviderInit, SessionDataLoadedGuard, AuthGuard],
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: () => import('./pages/contracts/contracts.module').then(m => m.ContractsPageModule)
        },
        {
          path: ':id',
          loadChildren: () => import('./pages/contracts/contracts.module').then(m => m.ContractsPageModule)
        }
      ]
}
```

The problem comes with a feature I implemented to open a chat from within an opened contract and vice versa.
Now when I jump between the pages and change the contract so different ids are used in the url as the param the page gets loaded multipe times, because it thinks its a different page to load.

Maybe one of you could help me find the reason for this or how to change the behaviour because I only want to have the contracts and chats pages loaded one time each:

This is a picture of my dom after I jumped between the pages:
[Dom structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KtfB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the child routes order. E.g:

```
{
    canActivate: [GlobalsProviderInit, SessionDataLoadedGuard, AuthGuard],
    path: ':username/chat',
    children: [
             {
                 path: ':id',
                 loadChildren: () => import('./pages/chat/chat.module').then(m => m.ChatPageModule)
             },
             {
                 path: '',
                 loadChildren: () => import('./pages/chat/chat.module').then(m => m.ChatPageModule)
             }
         ]
},
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but also when I just change the page from

david/chats/12 -> david/chats/14 it also generates a new page component, because it somehow searches for the pages whole url in the router outlet and there was only one with /12 at the end so it generates a new one. For now I switched to querry parameters, that way I have always the same url and the id is set as id in the params. (Xxx/?id=12)